# Vector3 subVector error in Dart

Tags: dart, vectormath

I get the following error when I try to use the SubVectors property on Dart (with three.dart and vector_math).

> The method 'subVector' is not defined for the class 'Vector3'

```
for(var x=0;x<width-1;x++){
          for(var y=0;y<height-1;y++){
              Vector3 vec0; Vector3 vec1;  Vector3 n_vec;
              // one of two triangle polygons in one rectangle
              vec0.subVectors(geometry.vertices[offset(x,y)],geometry.vertices[offset(x+1,y)]);
              vec1.subVectors(geometry.vertices[offset(x,y)],geometry.vertices[offset(x,y+1)]);
```

Comment: Shouldn't dart be able to provide the "-" operator for the Vector3 class so you can write:

`vec0 = geometry.vertices[offset(x,y)] - geometry.vertices[offset(x+1,y)`?

Comment: accepting anothers user's answer is kind of lame. but anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `vector_math` package doesn't have a `subVectors` method on the `Vector3` class. You can archive the same by writing the first value into `vec0` and then substracting the other one:

```
vec0.setFrom(geometry.vertices[offset(x,y)]);
vec0.sub(geometry.vertices[offset(x+1,y)]);
vec1.setFrom(geometry.vertices[offset(x,y)]); 
vec1.sub(geometry.vertices[offset(x,y+1)]);
```

This would require that `vec0` and `vec1` are already initialized with an `Vector3` instance.
As an alternative you could use the minus operator to substract the two values, but this would create a new instance:

```
vec0 = geometry.vertices[offset(x,y)] - geometry.vertices[offset(x+1,y)];
vec1 = geometry.vertices[offset(x,y)] - geometry.vertices[offset(x,y+1)];
```

You can check out the current `vector_math` documentation [here](http://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/vector_math/1.4.3/index.html#vector_math).